# Make Screen Compatibility Containing Canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas

I am working with canvas in android. i want to draw shapes on canvas which fits in every screen.
 if screen size is **320 * 240** then height & width with is **90 * 90** but 
 if **screen_size is > 320 * 240** then it should increase accordingly.

Suppose **screen_size = 1280 * 800** then how much it should increase

I don't know what to do for this

Code is Like

```
int fixHeight = 240, fixWidth = 320;
Paint paint;
paint = new Paint();
paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
     if (height <= fixHeight && width <= fixWidth) {
          canvas.drawRect(10, 10, 50, 50, paint);  
     } else {
          // Don't Know What TO Put Here
     }
}
```

Can any one help me

Comment: Post your onDraw method then someone can contribute the required chnages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `onDraw` method you might want to check the layout `height` and `width` of your `canvas` and adjust your draw.height and draw.width accordingly.

If the size has increased for the screen then you can use a multiplying factor to your draw.width and draw.height constants to either multiply or divide before drawing.

**EDIT:** After code was posted.

Lets say 320*240 is the base case for you to draw a rectangle of height as 40 and breadth as 40 that is `canvas.drawRect(10, 10, 50, 50, paint);`So left, top, right and bottom can be used to be modified in your case with a new resolution of 1280*800 using the below formula.

```
320 --> (50 - 10)
1280 --> (x - 10)
```

so `x = 10 + (50-10)*1280/320`

Try to repeat the same forumla for wdith and you should get your base co-ordinates. I believe you can adjust your 10, 10(which I am keeping here constant) to a new location based on the same above formula.

Comment: multiplying factor makes shape in too bigger size so it isn't possible to multiply

Comment: I Want to do some thing like webpage concept if we make it small then it will and when it gets bigger size page control will adjust automatically increases and adjust in same place

Comment: multiplying with 0.2, 0.02, 0.002 and so on should make it smaller.

Comment: Then you might want to implement a onTouchListener to your canvas and redraw whenever you get a pinch in or pinch out.

Comment: Thanks U Sana It Helps Me Lot