# How can i draw a circle that compatible with all android device with fixed radius?

Tags: java, android

I need to create a program, that have 5 radius buttons. When i'm click on these each button i want to adjust my circle radius.(Circle should have same size in all android phones).
pls help me to find this...

Answer (score 0):

You could create a circle-shape in xml and set this as background resource to a button or an imageButton, or you could do your own button-class and override onDraw method. A tutorial with shape is here:

http://dandar3.blogspot.de/2012/10/android-custom-round-buttons.html

or here:

http://yekmer.posterous.com/how-to-make-rounded-buttons-on-android

Instead of using "rectangle" at the shape, You could use "oval".

I don´t know if I understand You right, but making a button that had the same size on every phone is not a good way. Views had to be independent, a view should be created in a way, that it is adjusted to the individual screen size. To do so, use "dp" units in your xml layouts.

### Now here is my example:

1.) first create a shape-drawable in the drawable folder:

round_button_oval_shape.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="oval" >
        <solid android:color="#00ced1" />
    </shape>
```

2.) create a second shape in drawable folder:

rounded_button_oval_shape_pressed.xml

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:shape="oval" >
          <solid android:color="#008b8b" />
     </shape>
```

3.) create a selector in the drawable folder:

rounded_button_selector.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

       <item android:drawable="@drawable/rounded_button_oval_shape_pressed"
       android:state_pressed="true"></item>
       <item android:drawable="@drawable/round_button_oval_shape"
       android:state_pressed="false"></item>
       <item android:drawable="@drawable/round_button_oval_shape"></item>
    </selector>
```

4.)create your main-layout

main.xml

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:background="#000000"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:orientation="vertical" >

     <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="@string/hello_world"
       android:textColor="#ff0000" />

     <Button
       android:id="@+id/rounded_button"
       android:layout_width="250dp"
       android:layout_height="250dp"
       android:background="@drawable/rounded_button_selector" />

     </LinearLayout>
```

If you have done this parts, you could anything do with that button in your activity.

RoundedButtonDemo.java

```
    public class RoundedButtonDemo extends Activity {

private Button mRoundedButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mRoundedButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rounded_button); //initialize your button
    mRoundedButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {   // set Button on click listener

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(RoundedButtonDemo.this,            //show a toast when pressing button
                    R.string.rounded_button_message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }

    });
   }

    }
```

The shapes and the selector are needed for showing a pressed behavior of the button. The first shape is a normal button, which is not pressed. the second one is a shape that is pressed. The selector is using the two shapes for showing the pressed state to the user. To get this, set the selector as background to your button in your main.xml .

Answer (score 0):

Deducting the screen size before you create a circle and act based on that is a elegant way ,

There are difference sizes of screens in android devices,

so find out the screen size place your co-ordinate values according to the found screen size,

If drawing is only one option for you then the following 
thread will be helpful for you to achieve this,

[Compatible Canvas draw tip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11045071/make-screen-compatibility-containing-canvas)

If not, then button backgounds should be 9 patch image is always better.

Hope , you will find it useful.

Comment: Remember that on Android-Devices you'll have to consider two values: screen size and resolution. A circle of the same radius can end up in different sizes on two phones with same screen size but different resolution.